# MS Access Query to find gaps in sequential numbers when numbers are stored in Short Text field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table (tblParts) with a PartNumber field (Short Text) which stores 6 digit part numbers for parts belonging to several families. The families are denoted by the first 2 digits of the part number (00, 01, 02, etc). 
(NOTE: I did not create this table and am not able to change it at this time)

I need to find gaps in the numbering in order to fill in unused part numbers. If I have a project starting that needs 6 consecutive part numbers in a specific family, I want to find the first unused number in the first gap of that size or greater within that family.

Here is a small subset of the data.

```
PartNumber
020001
020002
020003
020004
020005
020006
020007
020009
020010
020011
020012
020013
020014
020019
020101
```

If I needed a single number, the query should find 020008. If I needed 3 numbers, it should find 0200015 and if I needed 10 numbers it should find 020020.

My SQL knowledge is very limited but I am trying to learn. I realize this would be much easier if the information was stored properly but I have no control over it.

Comment: Unfortunately, doing anything with incrementation in MS-Access SQL is an extremely arduous and painful task. I would highly suggest if you're trying anything with incrementation, you go with VBA.

Answer (score 1):

I once wrote an article on the subject:

[Find and Generate Missing Values in an Access Table](http://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/40345)

but that will fill up any gap until all new numbers were established. So, that code will need an expansion with an outer loop to ensure juxtaposed numbers at all times.

```vb
Private Sub btnSearch_Click()

' Read table/query sequentially to 
' record all missing IDs.
' Fill a ListBox with missing values.
' A reference to Microsoft DAO must be 
' present.

  ' Define search table or query.
  Const cstrTable As String = "Orders"
  Const cstrField As String = "OrderID"

  Dim dbs As DAO.Database
  Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
  Dim lst As ListBox
  Dim col As Collection

  Dim strSQL As String
  Dim strList As String
  Dim lngLast As Long
  Dim lngNext As Long
  Dim lngMiss As Long

  strSQL = "Select " & cstrField & "" _
   & " From " & cstrTable & _
   & " Order By 1;"  

  Set lst = Me!lstMissing
  Set col = New Collection
  Set dbs = CurrentDb
  Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

  If rst.RecordCount = 0 Then
    'The recordset is empty.
    'Nothing to do.
  Else
    lngLast = rst(cstrField).Value
    rst.MoveNext
    While rst.EOF = False
      lngNext = rst(cstrField).Value
      For lngMiss = lngLast + 1 To _
       lngNext - 1
        col.Add (lngMiss)
      Next
      lngLast = lngNext
      rst.MoveNext
    Wend
      'Generate next value in sequence.
      'Discard if collecting only 
      'missing values.
      col.Add (lngLast + 1)
  End If
  rst.Close

  'Populate list box from collection.
  For lngMiss = 1 To col.Count
    If Len(strList) > 0 Then 
      strList = strList & ";"
    End If
    strList = strList & col(lngMiss)
    Debug.Print col(lngMiss)
  Next
  lst.RowSource = strList
  Debug.Print strList

  Set rst = Nothing
  Set dbs = Nothing
  Set col = Nothing
  Set lst = Nothing

End Sub
```