# VBA ACCESS code autoincrementing a value with prefix

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I have a table named 'odonto' and it has the fields code (autoincremental), history, surnames and names. I need to generate the code so that it autogenerates the HISTORY obtaining the first letter of the last name which will then have to be concatenated with consecutive numbers for each letter. That is to say that if we have four "FLORES" and a "MENDOZA" in the register it shows in a text box the next samples:

F001
F002
F003
F004
M001
...

Also I need to keep in mind that if a record is deleted it will be replaced by incrementing it again.

I did it and it functions for the asigning value, but it doesn't replace the deleted one if it.

```
Private Sub APELLIDO_AfterUpdate()
Dim MyStr
MyStr = Left([APELLIDO], 1)
Me.LETRA = MyStr


If IsNull(Me.HISTORIA) Then

 Me!HISTORIA = ((MyStr) & "0000" & ([Cant] + 1))

Else
    
    HISTORIA = Me.HISTORIA
    
End If

Me.Refresh

End Sub
```

Please your help.

Comment: And what if you have 4 Flores and 3 Fuentes? What should the sequence be?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MS Access Query to find gaps in sequential numbers when numbers are stored in Short Text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840106/ms-access-query-to-find-gaps-in-sequential-numbers-when-numbers-are-stored-in-sh)

Comment: Another approach is to not delete record, just the data except for the Code value. Then your procedure would look for record where History IS NULL for the appropriate alpha prefix and use that record to populate with data and if none found then create a new sequence.